# How to write a file to csv when a column is 'struct' type?

Tags: dataframe, struct, pyspark, writetofile

I have an output spark Dataframe which needs to be written to CSV. A column in the Dataframe is 'struct' type and is not supported by csv. I am trying to convert it to string or convert to pandas DF but nothing works.

```
userRecs1=userRecs.withColumn("recommendations", explode(userRecs.recommendations))


#userRecs1.write.csv('/user-home/libraries/Sampled_data/datasets/rec_per_user.csv')
```

Expected result: Recommendations column as string type so that it can be split into two separate columns and write to csv.

Actual results:
(recommendations column is struct type and cannot be written to csv)

```
 ID_CTE|  recommendations|
+-------+-----------------+
|3974081| [2229,0.8915096]|
|3974081| [2224,0.8593609]|
|3974081| [2295,0.8577902]|
|3974081|[2248,0.29922757]| 
|3974081|[2299,0.28952467]|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command will *flatten* your `StructType` into separate named columns:

```py
userRecs1 \
  .select('ID_CTE', 'recommendations.*') \
  .write.csv('/user-home/libraries/Sampled_data/datasets/rec_per_user.csv')
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to convert the struct column to a json and then save:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
userRecs1 \
  .select(f.col('ID_CTE'), f.to_json(f.col('recommendations.'))) \
  .write.csv('/user-home/libraries/Sampled_data/datasets/rec_per_user.csv')
```