# Pyspark: Write CSV from JSON file with struct column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, struct

I'm reading a .json file that contains the structure below, and I need to generate a csv with this data in column form, I know that I can't directly write an array-type object in a csv, I used the explode function to remove the fields I need , being able to leave them in a columnar form, but when writing the data frame in csv, I'm getting an error when using the explode function, from what I understand it's not possible to do this with two variables in the same select, can someone help me with something alternative?

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, explode
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = (SparkSession.builder
    .master("local[1]")
    .appName("sample")
    .getOrCreate())

df = (spark.read.option("multiline", "true")
    .json("data/origin/crops.json"))

df2 = (explode('history').alias('history'), explode('trial').alias('trial'))
.select('history.started_at', 'history.finished_at', col('id'), trial.is_trial, trial.ws10_max))

(df2.write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv')
.mode('overwrite')
.option("header","true")
.save('data/output/'))

root
 |-- history: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- finished_at: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- started_at: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- trial: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- is_trial: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ws10_max: double (nullable = true)
```

I'm trying to return something like this

| started_at | finished_at | is_trial | ws10_max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | row |  |
| Second | row | row |  |

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a file to csv when a column is 'struct' type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57455986/how-to-write-a-file-to-csv-when-a-column-is-struct-type)

Comment: Hello @mckraqs, thanks for the answer, I had seen this post while I was researching the solution, I could not solve it the way it is presented there, my problem is a little different because I need to return the columns of two struct objects, and I have received an error message when I try to do the explode process for both elements, if I leave only one, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *explode* on array  and  select("struct.*") on struct.

```
df.select("trial", "id", explode('history').alias('history')),
  .select('id', 'history.*', 'trial.*'))
```